# Getting rid of Prompt while executing scp -p command on Solaris using putty

Tags: shell, solaris, putty

I am copying data from one server to another server using secure copy command on a solaris machine i.e. scp -p filename

While copying it is asking "Are you sure you want to continue connecting".

[image]

Is there a way to remove this prompt.I mean I want to copy without being asked for connecting.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you can do the ssh automation this wont be appearing again
Check this [link](http://wp.uberdose.com/2006/10/16/ssh-automatic-login/) for more info

Answer (score 0):

Use a text editor to edit the file `/export/home/loadusr/.ssh/known_hosts`.

Navigate to line 15, which is where an entry for an *old* host is. Delete that line.

To do this with *vi(m)*:

```
:15
dd
:wq
```